# The name 'cos' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, math, symbolic-math

I'm trying to derive using the math.net.symbolics library.

I am getting this error:
Compiler Error CS0103
The name 'cos' does not exist in the current context

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var x = Expr.Variable("x");
        var func = 2 * x * x - 2 * Trigonometric.Contract(cos(x)) + 1;     //exc. question: 2 * x * x - 2 * cos(x) + 1
        Console.WriteLine("f(x) = " + func.ToString());                     //answer: //4*x+2*sin(x)     

        var derivative = func.Differentiate(x);
        Console.WriteLine("f'(x) = " + derivative.ToString());
    }
```

Comment: Try using `x.Cos()` instead of `cos(x)`. The example on the web site using `cos(x)` is in F#. (And I suspect you'll need more changes than that - basically, read the part about using the library from C# very carefully.)

Comment: I got an error when I tried what you said. I used the documentation here: https://symbolics.mathdotnet.com/

Comment: As I noted, most of that documentation is for F# - and I specifically said that I suspected you'd need more changes than that. You should be looking at this section of the docs: https://symbolics.mathdotnet.com/#Math-NET-Symbolics-with-C-VB-NET-and-C-CLI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation is for F#. it wasn't working because I was writing code in C#.

Problem fixed when I used

```
x.Cos()
```

instead of

```
cos(x)
```